# Apple Time Machine with Netatalk: Don't have sufficient privileges

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, netatalk

I followed [these instructions](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.de/2012/11/time-capsule-for-25.html)

But I stopped at the very last step. I am asked twice to give user/pass: First, when I connect to the shared "TimeMachine Pi" (all good);

[image]

Then, after adding the RPi as capsule I am told

[image]

This is my configuration file

```
;
; Netatalk 3.x configuration file
;

[Global]
; Global server settings
; Name of your computer in apple devices network
hostname = TimeMachine Pi
; IP of your Pi
afp listen = 192.168.1.100
; logging config
log file = /var/log/netatalk.log
log level = default:info

[Homes]
basedir regex = /home
cnid scheme = dbd
; Display each user home directory in this format
home name = Home: $u

[Time Machine]
; Our Time Machine volume
path = /mnt/TimeMachine
cnid scheme = dbd
file perm = 0660
directory perm = 0770
time machine = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over a similar issue. In my case I forgot to make the directory on the server writable for the user that I was logging in with.

You can try making it group writable for your users:

```
$ chgrp users /mnt/TimeMachine
$ chmod g+rwX /mnt/TimeMachine
```